# Why I can reverse a string by passing a variable but not passing a real string? (simple code)

Tags: c, string, function, reversing

Here is the way how I can display the string "dcba":

```
main()
{
    char s[10] = "abcd";
    puts(strrev(s));
}
```

The way how I get a "Segmentation Fault" (why?):

```
puts(strrev("abcd"));
```

And here is the function that reverse the string:

```
char *strrev(char *s)
{
    int i, j;
    char aux;

    for(i=0, j=strlen(s)-1; i<j; i++, j--)
    {
        aux = s[j];
        s[j] = s[i];
        s[i] = aux;
    }

    return s;
}
```

Comment: A string literal is constant.

Comment: Careful, @overtheboard. While you are wise to *treat* literals as if they were constant, that word has a specific meaning in the standard. They are not *required* to be unchangable and, in fact, phase 6 creates an array of `char` rather than `const char`. I'm sure you meant the former but I'm feeling unwisely pedantic today :-)

Comment: This code works for me..

Comment: @Twinkle, sometime, undefined behaviour works (on some implementations, under certain circumstances, when compiled with certain flags and run on any day other than one following a blue moon). That is its most insidious property :-)

Answer (score 4):

In C, it's because trying to modify a string literal is one of the things that's considered undefined behaviour.

The reason literal string modification was marked as undefined behaviour in the original C standard (keeping in mind that the original intent of the ANSI/ISO C standards bodies was to codify existing practice rather than invent a new language) was because some implementations in existence at the time stored string literals in read-only memory, or shared identical string literals to reduce memory usage.

And, since each iteration of the standard after that point valued backward compatibility (and some implementations may *still* optimise for space or protect string literals from inadvertent corruption), there's been no real desire to change it.

Bottom line, undefined behaviour is generally bad, don't do it.

Comment: AFAIK, not just pre-standards. It is still done that way these days.

Comment: @Rudy, apologies, I didn't mean to suggest it wasn't done that way today, just that, because it was done that way before C89/90, they had to honour it. I'll try to change the answer to clarify.

Comment: no need to apologize. But literals are often still in read-only memory. Hence the segfault.